# Azure Storage Explorer not connecting to Azurite local emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer, azurite

**Context:** I've successfully installed [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite#install-and-run-the-azurite-visual-studio-code-extension), a local emulator (via the Visual Studio Code extension) and [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). I've also successfully placed a parquet file in the blob directory, started blob service in Azurite and confirmed in VSC that the file is there.

[image]
[image]

**Question:** When I try to connect to the emulator from Azure Storage Explorer, I don't see the parquet file. What am I doing wrong? Why do I not see the parquet file under either of the blob containers in ASE yet the file shows in VSC?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `parquet` file you put is invalid.

Because `__blobstorage__` directory did not store your containers and blobs, [refer to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite#workspace-structure):

> **blobstorage** - Directory containing Azurite blob service persisted binary data

As we can see, you have connected to your azurite successfully. Just upload your file using Storage Explorer.

Comment: @ Doris Lv thanks. It sounds like you're saying _blobstorage_ isnt the right place to put the file. Where is the correct directory?

Comment: @emalcolmb, Usually we view and manage the blob using Storage Explorer. Sorry I didn't find a place where described how azurite works background, but for Azure storage emulator, "the Storage Emulator uses a local Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB instance to emulate Azure storage services."

Comment: Do you know wherr I can find steps to load the file into Azurite using the Storage Explorer?

Comment: @emalcolmb , click *local-1* account, right click *blob container*,choose *create blob container*, then click the container you created just now, then you can manage your blob file in this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access through the local connection string.

```
<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```

Comment: How do I find that?

Comment: I edit my answer... for some reason was not appearing the XML part.